# How to map a segment of a route to routeParams?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Lets say I have two routes defined, served by the same view and controller, such as

- /customers/:cutomerId/edit
- /customers/add

in a controller I need to determine in which "mode" is view in. How do I map "edit" and "add" segments of the route so that it appears in $routeParams. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

You may user route's resolves to solve it.

For example:

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('/customers/:cutomerId/edit', {
    templateUrl: 'myView.html',
    controller: 'MyController',
    resolve: {
      mode: function() {
        return 'edit';
      }
    }
  })
  .when('/customers/add', {
    templateUrl: 'myView.html',
    controller: 'MyController',
    resolve: {
      mode: function() {
        return 'add';
      }
    }
  });

myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, mode){
   // Now controller knows it's mode.
});
```